# Possible to register multiple custom taxonomies in one function?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I'm registering 7 custom taxonomies in my functions.php. Since each function uses the same labels and arguments and is attached to the same Custom Post Type, I'm wondering if it's possible to register all the taxonomies in 1 function? Here is the code that is repeated 7 times with the `<XXX>` as the only changing parts:

```
function custom_taxonomy_<XXX> ()  {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => '<XXX>',
    'singular_name'              => '<XXX>',
    'menu_name'                  => '<XXX>s',
    'all_items'                  => 'All <XXX>s',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent <XXX>',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent <XXX>:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New <XXX> Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New <XXX>',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit <XXX>',
    'update_item'                => 'Update <XXX>',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate <XXX> with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search <XXX>s',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or Remove <XXX>s',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used <XXX>s',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var'                  => true,                       
);
register_taxonomy( '<XXX>', 'custom_post_type', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_<XXX>', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Not the WordPress way at least.

You could probably make helper function (plain PHP realm in other words) to build instances of label arrays, however that would seriously hinder making strings translatable.

Comment: Thank you, Rarst. I was thinking of something along those lines. I do not need the strings to be translatable (to other languages, if that is what you mean). Can you point me in the direction of that type of helper function code?

Comment: even when not translatable, labels have a way of mutating into different directions over time. The extra lines of codes being saved are just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a wrapping function that can provide values for all those `XXX's` at runtime. Here's a rough, untested example:

```php
function build_and_register_custom_taxonomy($taxonomy_name, $taxonomy_menu_name, $priority) {
  $definition = function($taxonomy_name) {
    $labels = array(
      'name'                       => $taxonomy_name,
      'singular_name'              => $taxonomy_name,
      'menu_name'                  => "${taxonomy_menu_name}"
      // etc...
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels'                     => $labels,
      'hierarchical'               => true,
      'public'                     => true,
      'show_ui'                    => true,
      'show_admin_column'          => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
      'show_tagcloud'              => true,
      'query_var'                  => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy($taxonomy_name, 'custom_post_type', $args );
  }
  add_action('init', $definition, $priority);
}

build_and_register_custom_taxonomy('news_item', 'News Items', 0)
```

You'd need to finish the implementation here, but the idea is to keep the number of necessary parameters to a minimum while still populating the entire `$labels` array with the appropriate values.

You may end up with the `build_and_register_custom_taxonomy` function accepting 8 arguments, or perhaps just the three or four.

You could also override portions of the `$args` array by passing down arguments from the parent `build_and_register_custom_taxonomy` function as needed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. That's out of my skill level at this time. I've found just doing a modular functions.php file (that brings in each custom post type with require_once() calls) was a nice way to clean up things so there wasn't 8 blobs of code all together for each custom post type.