# How to get child taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

This is the custom post type structure I have:

Custom Post Type

- Custom Taxonomy

  - Sub Taxonomy 1
  - Sub Taxonomy 2
  - Sub Taxonomy 3

On the current Custom Post Type post/page, I need the code that finds the Sub Taxonomy (or Sub Taxonomies) of that post and output it as a link to other posts with the same sub taxonomy (separated by a comma, if it has more than one Sub Taxonomy).

The following code is close to what I'm looking for but I need it for the current post, I don't want it as a list and there has to be a comma separating them if there's more than one

```
<?php
$term_id = 10;
$taxonomy_name = 'products';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119491/4771) may help you out.

Comment: Is this resolved and can be marked as duplicate of said thread then? :)