# List only child categories a post is in, of a specific parent category in wordpress

Tags: categories

I am building a quotes website and i have 2 main categories like **Topic** & **Authors** 
 Every quote will have Author name and topic name and those are sub categories of Topic & Author.
 **AND my question is**
 i want to display only Author categories that is a sub category of a Authors category please help me...

**Topic**
 - Love
 - Life
 - Friends etc
**Authors**
 - Author1
 - Author2
 - Author3

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the same structure as shown above:

```
wp_list_categories(array('hide_empty'=>0, 'hierarchical' => true, 'include' => array('12','12')));
```

Comment: i want some thing like this
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119486/list-only-child-categories-a-post-is-in-of-a-specific-parent-category

Comment: Use this updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        // names / IDs of parents
        $parents = array(
            'par2' => 76
        );
        // get post categories
        $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        // output top level cats and their children
        foreach( $parents as $parent_name => $parent_id ):
        // output parent name and link
        //echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $parent_id, 'category' ) . '">' . $parent_name . '</a>: ';
        // initialize array to hold child links
        $links = array();
        foreach( $categories as $category ):
        if( $parent_id == $category->parent ):
        // put link in array
        $links[] = '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        endif;
        endforeach;
        // join and output links with separator
        echo join($links );
        endforeach;            
    ?>
```

*This is the answer i am looking for thanks for replys*